# Oracle SQL ability to add filter on Sysdate which accepts negative and posstive values in days

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle-sqldeveloper

SQL newb here. I'm trying to adjust the filters in my Oracle SQL report, I would like the filter to accept both negative (-) and possitive (+) values.

This is my SQL line:

```
Work_day <= to_date(sysdate+'&Days_from_current_date')
```

Problem I'm only able to add + days from the sysdate, I would like to have filter which would accepts:

```
-XX days from the sysdate
+XX days from the sysdate
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `SYSDATE` is a function that returns `DATE` datatype, so it is wrong to `TO_DATE` it.

Code you posted *should* work (there's no evidence it doesn't; could you provide sample data and desired output?).

This is "now":

```
SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
-------------------
03.03.2022 09:05:04
```

Query:

```
SQL> with test (name, work_day) as
  2    (select 'Little', date '2022-03-01' from dual union all
  3     select 'Foot'  , date '2022-03-15' from dual
  4    )
  5  select *
  6  from test
  7  where work_day <= trunc(sysdate) + &days_from_current_date;
Enter value for days_from_current_date: 2

NAME   WORK_DAY
------ -------------------
Little 01.03.2022 00:00:00

SQL> /
Enter value for days_from_current_date: -1

NAME   WORK_DAY
------ -------------------
Little 01.03.2022 00:00:00

SQL> /
Enter value for days_from_current_date: 20

NAME   WORK_DAY
------ -------------------
Little 01.03.2022 00:00:00
Foot   15.03.2022 00:00:00

SQL>
```